# TIBQuery: проверка существования поля

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты! Помню, что есть но не могу вспомнить и найти метод проверки поля на существование. Если кто помнит - прошу подсказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
if IBQuery1.FindField('id')=nil then
  ShowMessage('Нет такого поля');
```